# Exporting To Excel from Access ignores formatting

Tags: database, excel, ms-access

I'm exporting a query from Access to ".xls" and it seems that Excel ignores the formatting I had in place for a cell. It's turning my integer into a number with leading decimals.

I tried work around, even adding a input mask of "999" but once exported I still get numbers like "13.9511797312704" rather than "13".

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you double click the cells in Access you will see that they are just hiding decimals. Even with a mask the decimals are there, they are just masked. Hence the term "mask". Excel isn't going to mask them by default, so when exporting you see them for what they are.

There is more than one way to do it, one of which I don't recommend, that is format(), or more specifically formatnumber(), I dont recommend because this function formats the numbers into a string/text format. Thats horrible for business math and spreadsheet work.

What works is using the convert function, such as cint(). Careful as this function doesn't play nice with Null values.

Here is a working code that should get Excel to obey! Hehe

```
AR Term: IIf([SumOfBilled USD]<>0,IIf(IsNull([SumOfDaysX]/[SumOfBilled USD]),0,CInt([SumOfDaysX]/[SumOfBilled USD])),IIf(IsNull([SumOfDaysX]/[SumOfBilled RMB]),0,CInt([SumOfDaysX]/[SumOfBilled RMB])))
```

[image]

[image]